# How to add days to a date in mysql

Tags: mysql

kindly give your valuable suggestion to sort following mysql query.

days give the no of days available for the project eg: 6

`Received_date` shows the starting date of the project in this format   eg: `2017-03-27`

So I just need to get the value of the `Expired_date` using **MYSQL**

```
Expired_date (Received_date + days ) = 2017-04-03
```

kindly tell me what should i include in the ** some query **

```
SELECT
     tsc_document_status.warehouse_transfer_note_id,
     tsc_document_status.tsc_allocated_days AS days,
     tsc_document_status.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_date AS Received_date
     (******* some query ****) AS Expired_date
FROM
     tsc_document_status
```

Comment: `DATE_ADD(received_date, INTERVAL tsc_document_status.tsc_allocated_days DAY)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DATE_ADD` function.

```
SELECT
t.warehouse_transfer_note_id,
t.tsc_allocated_days AS days,
t.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_date AS Received_date,
DATE_ADD(t.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_date, INTERVAL t.tsc_allocated_days DAY) AS Expired_date
FROM
tsc_document_status AS t
```

Comment: SELECT
tsc_document_status.warehouse_transfer_note_id,
tsc_document_status.tsc_allocated_days AS days,
tsc_document_status.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_date AS Received_date,
DATE_ADD(tsc_document_status.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_date, INTERVAL tsc_document_status.tsc_allocated_days DAY) AS Expired_date
FROM
tsc_document_status